# Calculate averages in Python nested list: if elements 1 and 2 match, average element 3

Tags: python, list, average

I'm attempting to calculate averages without using Pandas dataframes or the mean function (for practice). I have nested lists and would like to average the third element of the inner lists if the first and second elements match.

Example input:

```
mylist = [[USD, 2000, 13.40], [USD, 2000, 13.68], [USD, 2001, 13.99], [EUR, 2000, 10.50], [EUR, 2000, 11.02]]
```

The desired output is:

```
avlist = [[USD, 2000, 13.54], [USD, 2001, 13.99], [EUR, 2000, 10.76]]
```

The furthest I've gotten is to make a set from the first 2 elements and find the intersection with the original lists:

```
unique_list = list(set([x[0:2] for x in mylist]))
if (y for y in ([x[0:2] for x in mylist]) if y in unique_list):
   # av_list =
```

Is it possible to then do something like 'where this intersection is true, add the third elements in my_list to a third element in unique_list and divide by the number of elements added'?

I hope the question is clear.

Comment: i think you're trying to make your code too short.  break this up into lots of small tasks. First make a list of currency-year pairs.  Then iterate through that list finding matches in your original list. Think about what data structures are available to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by grouping your data according to the keys you want to use to control the averaging:

```
>>> mylist = [['USD', 2000, 13.40], ['USD', 2000, 13.68], ['USD', 2001, 13.99], ['EUR', 2000, 10.50], ['EUR', 2000, 11.02]] 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mydict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for curr, year, value in mylist:
        mydict[(curr,year)].append(value)
```

That will give you the numbers you want to average as lists:

```
>>> mydict
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {('USD', 2000): [13.4, 13.68], ('USD', 2001): [13.99], ('EUR', 2000): [10.5, 11.02]})
```

Then average each of the lists:

```
>>> for (curr, year), values in mydict.items():
        print (curr, year, sum(values)/len(values))

USD 2000 13.54
USD 2001 13.99
EUR 2000 10.76
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary, keyed by the items you want to match on e.g.

```
data = {}
for item in mylist:
     key = tuple(item[0:2])
     values = data.get(key, [])
     values.append(item[2])
     data[key] = values

# {('EUR', 2000): [10.5, 11.02], ('USD', 2000): [13.4, 13.68], ('USD', 2001): [13.99]}
```

Then you can go through each item in the dictionary and calculate your average.

```
for key in data:
     average = sum(data[key])/len(data[key])
     print('{}, average = {}'.format(key, average))
```